# Converting RDD with an Array to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following RDD

```
RDD[(Long, Array[(Long, Double)])]
```

I want to convert this into an Data Frame. 
I am using the following code

```
val aStruct = new StructType(Array(
    StructField("id", LongType,nullable = true),
    StructField("neighbors",ArrayType(
        StructType(Array(
            StructField("nid", LongType),
            StructField("distance", DoubleType)
    ))),nullable = true)))
val rowRDD = neighbors.map(p => Row(p._1, p._2))
val neighborsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD,aStruct)
```

This compiles correctly, but gives me a runtime error

```
 Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.Tuple2$mcJD$sp is not a valid external type for schema of struct<nid:bigint,distance:double>
```

Is my schema not proper ?

I tried also

```
import spark.implicits._
val neighborsDF = neighbors.toDF()
```

But for this i get the following Run time error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;
```

At the line i called the toDF()

What am I doing wrong here ? (I am expecting a lot :p )

So I do understant the problem, I have an Array of tuples in the RDD, but i cant seem to find Tuple type for Spark SQL Schema

Comment: Second problem is because of mismatched Scala versions on compile and runtime and/or Scala versions of libs

Comment: @T.Gawęda Actually You are right, that issue does exist. in my build.sbt i had scala version 2.10.5 while i had scala version 2.12.1 installed on my system. I just downloaded 2.10.5 and set my path to it and checked via scala -version , it is 2.10.5. But I am still getting the same error

Comment: Check also Spark version, if it contains `2.11` in name, it's compiled for Scala 2.11. Spark 2.x is by default built on Scala 2.11

Comment: @T.Gawęda Spark  2.10 Using Scala version 2.11.8.
But when I use 2.11.8 in my build.sbt and compile using sbt compile. I am getting two errors in my code ...Time to debug i guess

Comment: @T.Gawęda so the problem is, i am using a library for N nearest neighbors.  They use scala version 2.10.5. I tried compiling their code using scala version 2.11.8 in the build.sbt, it gives errors. And i cant seem to debug it. So yah thats a dead end

Comment: What is the lib you want to have?

Comment: @T.Gawęda spark-neighbors. Its a library that calculates your n nearest neighbor using LSH.  https://github.com/karlhigley/spark-neighbors

Comment: @T.Gawęda hey, Thank you for pointing out the error. So i built my own distribution of spark 2.1.0 with scala version 2.10.6. So now the compile version of scala and the version spark is using are same and .toDF() works. I know scala version 2.10.x is depreciated and might soon not be supported, but at the moment this will have to do. 
Thank you so much for pointing that out, you saved me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @T.Gawęda pointed out, I was using a separate version of Scala for compilation (2.10.6) and at runtime as pre-built Spark 2.1.0 comes with Scala Version 2.11.8. This resulted in the following error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse.runtimeMirror(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lscala/reflect/api/JavaMirrors$JavaMirror;`

When using

`neighborsDF = neighbors.toDF()`

So I had to compile my code with the right version of scala,but since a library i am using (spark-neighbors) throws compilation error when using Scala Version 2.11.8, so updating the scala version for my project wasnt really possible. 
So I decided to build a version of Spark with Scala 2.10.6 using the guide from the link [Building for Scala 2.10](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-210)

So now my Spark runs with Scala Version 2.10.6 and I use the same version to compile my code using sbt. Thus the RDD gets converted to dataframe without any error.
Hope it help others out as well